# Capturing 15MP images from a Logitech c920 webcam

Tags: windows, computer-vision, hardware, webcam, logitech

I am trying to take 15 Megapixel images with a Logitech c920.

The camera supports full-HD (2.1 MP) video, and 15MP static images.

Using the supplied Logitech Software, I can indeed save 15MP images. But if I access the camera directly via DirectShow, I can at most get the full-HD resolution. It seems like the camera is stuck in "video" mode.

I tried various examples for accessing webcams, namely [RobotEyez](https://github.com/tedburke/RobotEyez/blob/master/RobotEyez.cpp), [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html), [NirSoft WebCamImageSave](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/web_cam_image_capture.html).

I am beginning to suspect that the default interfaces for webcams under windows are only designed for video, and that there is no official way to tell the camera to take still images in higher resolution than the video stream.

How can I access such a device under windows in order to capture the full 15MP resolution supported for still images?

Comment: See [How to take a still photo in either DirectShow or Media Foundation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31483640/how-to-take-a-still-photo-in-either-directshow-or-media-foundation)